Expo RN app - Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager
React native project on Expo with the following packages installed:
    "@react-native/eslint-plugin": "^0.75.0-main",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@realm/react": "^0.6.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "^50.0.19",
    "expo-dev-client": "^3.3.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",

Trying to set up a Bottom Tabs react navigation, but I keep getting the error

"Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not
found in the UIManager"

I have precisely followed the steps presented in the React Navigation 6.x docs:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import InsertEntry from "@/components/molecules/InsertEntry";

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tabs.Navigator>
        <Tabs.Screen name="Home" component={InsertEntry} />
      </Tabs.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

I know there is this question that might be related, but nothing from there seemed to help.
